# Is Siddhartha Gautama the last recognized Buddha?

Tags: the-buddha

Does Siddharta Gautama happen to be the last person to reach Buddhahood?

Comment: I think that it depends on which sect/branch of buddhism one is looking at. I know that in Nochiren Buddhism, Nichiren Daishonin is often referred to as, "The Buddha of the Latter-Day of the Law."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you think in terms of a fully enlightened Buddhas. Maytrea Buddha will be the next. However, there are also private Buddhas. Most of Buddhas are private Buddhas. They are enlightened, but they don't teach the Dhamma.

Comment: are you revering to paccekabuddha's?

Comment: pacceka buddhas = private buddhas

Answer (score 6):

To add to @konrad01, private Buddhas don't occur when the dispensation of a Buddha is still there. Hence the last Buddha is Siddhartha Gautama.